Why can't I generate coredumps in Ubuntu 24?
I have tried setting "ulimit -c unlimited". And I have edited the "/etc/security/limits.conf" and set the first line to unlimited. I have restarted apport. I have restarted my system.
However, when I run my program (with AddressSanitizer enabled and configured to create coredumps), "/var/log/apport.log" prints "core limit 0".
What on earth could be the problem?
If you need further configuration settings, please tell me how to produce them.
Thank you.

It was AddressSanitizer. I found the answer on this page: stackoverflow.com/questions/42851670/… --> I did not read the 64bit instructions shown on that page.

Link correction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851670/how-to-generate-core-dump-on-addresssanitizer-error
